# Making api calls from React component using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have got one question which bothers me a lot when I work with React and Redux. In my application I have my own API middleware for making api calls using plain actions. It makes fetch under the hood and returns Promise, works great. But sometimes I have a feeling that data I would like to get does not fit in my store and should not be there ex. it is only important for single component and shouldn't be global.

What do I mean exactly, this is how I normally do data fetching. I make an action creator like this:

```
dispatch(apiCall({ url, type, typePrefix })
```

`typePrefix` is prefix for request, success and failure actions ex. `${typePrefix}/REQUEST`. After that I can react to these actions in my reducer.

Now, sometimes I am thinking about just making `fetch` in my provider/container component, save it to local state and pass it down to presentational component.
When I use Redux are thunks (or sagas) an only way to perform data fetching or is it fine to sometimes keep fetched data locally? I haven't found any question about it.

Comment: There's no general answer, but IMO the Redux store is for state that needs to be shared among components--there's no reason to share data across the entire app if only single components or small trees need that data or have to act on "things" related to that data (like if it's been retrieved yet or not). Same reason with Redux it still makes sense to have component state vs. mapping Redux state to props. That said, having it available in the store means you can do things with it you didn't originally anticipate.

Comment: Yes, local state is essential and I've never felt that I have to put everything in a store, but if action creators are a way to perform side effects it's implication should be store update. As I said, sometimes I just want to fetch data but don't store it and I wonder if it is ok when already using Redux.

Comment: Where the data comes from isn't really relevant, e.g., for UI components' local state there's no reason to use Redux, even if it might be consuming data from the Redux store. That could just as easily extend to externally-fetched resources. Ultimately it always boils down to what makes sense in the context of your application, and there's no reason it can't be changed later. Redux isn't "all or nothing", it's "as needed", and there's no reason not to mix state.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from one of the creators of Redux:

> I would like to amend this: don't use Redux until you have problems with vanilla React.

Redux is mainly required if you are finding it cumbersome to :

- Pass same state across nested children.
- Maintain multiple copies of same information across several components.

But if you feel redux is just complicating stuff, you should just stick to vanilla React and JS.

More on that can be read [here](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367).

Comment: I don't think that I have problem with understanding or using Redux. I do have situations where fetched data is shared across multiple components, but as 
 I mentioned in my question - it is not fine for me to keep "not shared" state in store. Also I think it is not a nooby question.

Comment: Its not nooby. I never said so. If you feel some information can be localised within a component, then that is perfectly fine. Redux is not meant to store every API's response. 
At a later point, if you feel the data is being passed around several layers, you can always move it to redux.

Comment: That is more the anwser I expected, thank you :) I think that problem I mentioned should also be point out somewhere in Redux documentation. Not sure if other people also met with the same problem.

Comment: There is a slight mention here : https://redux.js.org/faq/general#when-should-i-use-redux. But a more detailed article was written by Dan. Have linked above.

Comment: But these two links are 0-1 options, you may use Redux or don't use it at all. My point is that I find Redux useful in my app, but sometimes there are situations where I feel that I should't call action creator to fetch my data, store it and pass it down through connect. Sometimes I would like make it just Vanilla React way. This is my point, it is not a question if shall I use it or leave it.

Comment: This is more of a guideline rather than a hard and fast rule. You can always use redux for storing some data, and React's component state for storing other.
That said, if you are going the redux way, storing all data in redux would be recommended as it would make your app more maintainable.